# The equivalence between cubical sets with connection and cubical $\omega$-groupoid with connection.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

In the paper Cubical abelian groups with connections are equivalent to chain complexes as seen here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212157.pdf it is asserted that cubical sets with connection and cubical $\omega$-groupoid with connection are equivalent.
[image]

[image]

It is clear that every $\omega$-groupid can be included into cubical set, but what is the $\omega$-groupoid associated to each cubical set?

My first thought was for cubical set $X$, take $FX$, the free cubical abliean group on $X$. However, this doesn't seem to be a $\omega$-groupoid, as there doesn't seem to be a way to define $-_j$.

Thanks for your help!